# Laravel test. assert exact JSON structure

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-testing

I have a laravel API project. There is a lot security data, that shouldn't be shown for users in API responses. I need some way to write tests where I can get `true` if only the response structure is exact same as a pre-set structure in test.

So, if my test structure is `$structure = [ 'data' => ['_id', 'user' => ['name', 'email], 'title'];` but in response I'm recieveing more or less fields, I need this test to be failed.

In a docs I've found only:

`assertJson` - expecting for exact key => values, but I need a keys only;
`assertJsonStructure` - returns true even if some fields missing or response contains some other fields.

Comment: you can make a custom function for that

Comment: @N69S sure I can. But I'm looking for something existing first.

Comment: Do you want to test only the structure or also the data? If you want to test the data you can use `$this->assertEquals(..., ...)`, if you want to be sure that some values is not shown you can use `$this->assertArrayNotHasKey();`

Answer (score 1):

Use [**Opis JSON Schema**](https://opis.io/json-schema)

```php
$validator = new \Opis\JsonSchema\Validator();
$result = $validator->dataValidation($json, $schema);
PHPUnit::assertTrue($result->isValid(), "Mismatch json schema");
```

For your case read more about `required` and `additionalProperties`: https://docs.opis.io/json-schema/1.x/object.html#required

Your json scheme may be looks like:

```
{
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "required": [
        "id"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: Looks good. Can I require embedded structures?
Like ` [ require: ['_id' , 'title', 'user', 'user.name' , ' user.age'] ` .

Comment: Yes. I updated my answer and added an example json scheme to it.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `assertJsonCount()` to make sure you have the expected number of keys?

I have a `DataTests` class that contains a public static function that returns an array with the expected keys from my endpoint. If it returns more fields or less fields the count doen't match and the assertion fails.

DataTests.php

```php
public static function arrayStructure(): array {
        return [
            //keys
        ];
    }
```

MyTest.php

```php
public function test_array_structure() {
    $this->withHeaders($headers)->post(), [])
        ->assertJsonStructure(DataTests::arrayStructure())
        ->assertJsonCount(count(DataTests::arrayStructure(), COUNT_RECURSIVE));
    }
```

That way if I add a new column to my array in the future my tests will fail if I don't add the new value to my `arrayStructure()`.